# Black screen after login for my user account only

Tags: windows-7, login, black-screen-of-death

I ran into a perplexing issue today.

I was attempting to roll out an Access Database file to certain users. I set up a namespace and replication, then proceeded to set up a network mapped drive from a new group policy object using the replication and namespace. As I put myself into the Active Directory group, I restarted my computer so I would pick up the permissions of the new group.

When I restarted and logged on, I got a black screen with a cursor! So far, these are the steps I have tried:

- Restarting the computer and trying to log on 3 times: no luck.
- Restarting the computer and logging on, then waiting an hour: no luck.
- Logging on to the computer as domain administrator: works fine.
- Logging on to the computer as local administrator: works fine.
- Running event view: Unable to resolve username in Group Policy.
- Deleting the user and profile from the computer, restarting and logging on: Still the same black screen.
- Renaming the user profile on the server, deleting the profile on the local computer, and removing user: no luck.
- Deleting myself from AD and removing user profile. Kept the old profile but added .OLD to the end. Removed my profile from the computer and deleted the user. Added myself as a new user, and logged onto computer: Now I get a light blue screen and a cursor.
- Deleting computer from AD and rejoining: no luck.
- Logging on to 2 other computers: The profile is fine; no issues apart from the fact I've lost all my settings.

Conclusion: It is not my profile or settings or Group Policy. One thing to note is that my computer doesn't allow domain users to log in and there are only two users capable of administration of users – that is, myself and my other colleague – this is by choice. And I don't think this is causing the issue.

Has anyone experienced this before? I think the issue is computer-related and related to my specific username, rather than anything else. Perhaps a registry flus ? DNS Flush? or a complete roll-back?

One of the things I tend not to do is a shutdown; I tend to hibernate. Most of the time I'm in the middle of some work at home time and I don't want to lose my place in design work.

Comment: I would try the rollback.  The blue screen indicates you were unable to connect to the domain to retrieve your desktop.  The solution to that problem is to manually run explorer.exe

Comment: Just a thought but maybe it is group policy if i added myself to a group the group is not allowed to access the computer and add a mapped drive this causing a hang at logon? I will try in the morning adding the group to the list of administrators in the user accounts of the computer.

Comment: @Ramhound If all else fails i think this maybe my only choice, It's strange how it's only my username on this computer.

Answer (score 1):

I hade a user who have the same problem.
He could hit Ctrl,Alt,Del and then he get a screen but if he chose the task manager the picture became black again.
My solution on this was I think that his computer had get in to sleepmode on his profile.
If I chose change user and login with my account it was no problem.
After that I did a normal restart and the computer was standing in WIndows is shutingdown a log time and after that new updates was installed.
After the restart the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on one of my domains right now.

It actually affects local users too though if you're not careful.

**What i did to fix it was created a group policy to add the "domain users" group to the local machine's built in "users" group.**

Now my issue is that it keeps happening to a hand full of machines and you have to manually update GP before it will let them log on again.

My gut tells me it's a corrupt group policy, but as stated above removing from the domain and so on has done no good.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this - when a domain admin is in the local administrators group but not in the local "users" group, you get the black/blue/blank lazy login screen where you cannot use windows.

Answer (score 0):

Still wondering if the group policy is at play.

Check out the RSOP for the affected computer as compared when you log into one of the other computers with no issues. Take a look at the following page with instructions on how to run on another computer to grab the resultant policies for the computer in question:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323276

Comment: Please see my comment above, i had a thought? what do you think.

Answer (score 0):

I once had this issue,

But I think a Software Restriction group policy is causing this. 
In my case, 90% of users had this issue, the black screen and cursor, 9% could log in, but couldn't see task bar or create folder etc, then 1% didn't have any issues because they didn't restart their pcs the previous day

I simply went back to the group policy editor and removed the rule (I put it there the previous day)

It was resolved, 
Check your Software Restriction Policies, its under Security Settings, under Windows Settings

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for one of my domain users due to corrupt group policy.post moved the user into different OU the group policy was applied properly and the black screen issue sorted out.

Comment: group policies being the issue has already been answered